# How to share a NetLogo model online

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to share my NetLogo model online so that it can be run by others on their laptops or smartphones without NetLogo desktop installed.

I have found that it is possible to run models online with NetLogo web (http://www.netlogoweb.org/launch#http://www.netlogoweb.org/assets/modelslib/Sample%20Models/Biology/Evolution/Cooperation.nlogo) and also possible to upload a model from NetLogo to NetLogo web. The uploaded model can be exported as a .html file.

What I am having trouble with is creating a link for the .html file which others can run. I have tried sharing the .html file name directly and also depositing it in an open access folder in Dropbox and Google Drive. While the link is accessible in Dropbox or Google drive, the file will not run.

Any suggestions for what to try next would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "the file will not run", what happens exactly? Is there an error message? Also, can you provide a link to the broken page?

Answer (score 3):

You're far from the first person to run into this problem, so I've added a section to the NetLogo Web FAQ to explain the situation and what the solutions look like.  You can find the text [here](http://netlogoweb.org/info#hosting-nlw-files), or inline at the bottom of this post.

However, I don't think you really need the whole mini-essay that I wrote.  It sounds to me like you wanted to use Dropbox, but it just wasn't apparent **how**.  As it turns out, [the Dropbox documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16) provides a good guide for how you can host files publicly on Dropbox.  If you follow their instructions, I think you should end up with some files that are easily shareable.  Regarding how to specifically use your Dropbox file public URLs with NetLogo Web, you can see the paragraph about Dropbox in the FAQ text for more details.

#### Text from FAQ:

> To put it concisely, the only thing required is a hosting service that allows directly linking to hosted files.  However, free and simple to use hosting services are surprisingly few in number these days.  We realize that this makes things difficult for many of our users, and we definitely plan to provide our own service that makes this easier for people in the future.  For the time being, though, there are still a couple of options that we can suggest.
>
> For the vast majority of NetLogo Web users, a great option is to use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), which is a cost-free option for file-hosting.  To host NetLogo Web files on Dropbox, you must host them **publicly** (as explained [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16)).  Once you've done that, if your file is a `.nlogo` file, follow the instructions given [here](/info#generate-simple-pages), and share the `//netlogoweb.org/web?modelURL` link, using the public link URL from Dropbox for the `modelURL` value.  If instead, your file is a HTML standalone model (as generated by following the instructions in the section about "Export: HTML" [here](/info#saving)), then simply share the public link that you got from Dropbox, since it will point directly to the model.
>
> [GitHub](https://www.github.com/) is also a good alternative to Dropbox for this.  Instructions for how to host files on GitHub can be found [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/free-file-hosting-github/29092/).
>
> Another option is to use the [Modeling Commons](http://modelingcommons.org), which is a public space for uploading, sharing, and discussing NetLogo models.  All models uploaded to the Modeling Commons have integration with NetLogo Web through the "Run in NetLogo Web" tab on the model's page.  For any model, if you open that "Run" tab and then copy your browser's current URL, that URL can be used for direct access to the NetLogo Web version of the model.
>
> One other option (for more advanced users) is to host the files yourself on a public-facing web server that you have access to.  If you want to host an HTML standalone model (as generated by following the instructions in the section about "Export: HTML" [here](https://netlogoweb.org/info#saving)), then simply host it and distribute the link to where you're hosting the HTML file.
>
> Hosting a `.nlogo` file on a web server is more complicated, though.  To do that, host the file, and make sure that your web server allows it to be accessed cross-origin.  To do this, you might need to have the server set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the `.nlogo` file's HTTP response to either `*` or whichever NetLogo Web domain you're using (i.e.  `http://netlogoweb.org` or `https://netlogoweb.org` or `http://netlogo-web.org` or `https://netlogo-web.org`).  Then, follow the instructions given [here](https://netlogoweb.org/info#generate-simple-pages), and share your model through the `//netlogoweb.org/web?modelURL` link, using the URL of the model on the web server for the `modelURL` value.

Comment: Another option, for someone using GitHub, would be to point the "raw" file URL, e.g.: http://netlogoweb.org/web?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetLogo/models/master/Sample%20Models/Biology/Wolf%20Sheep%20Predation.nlogo

Comment: @jason - the URL to the page for hosting Dropbox files publicly appears to be broken. Can you suggest another source for this?

Comment: Here is a `.nlogo` file shared publicly through Dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24792346/josh_test.nlogo; per these (really helpful) instructions when I use http://www.netlogoweb.org/web?#https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24792346/josh_test.nlogo, the page does not load; when I replace `web` with `launch`, http://www.netlogoweb.org/launch?#https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24792346/josh_test.nlogo, it appears to load.

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg, the reason the `/web` URL doesn't work is because of the erroneous `#` in your URL.  Also, thanks for letting me know that the article link is broken.  I've updated netlogoweb.org and my answer here to point to Dropbox's instructions for how to publicly host files.

Comment: In light of Dropbox ending public sharing, and some problems sharing via GitHub, I asked a new question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893176/how-to-share-a-netlogo-model-through-github