# How to share a NetLogo model through GitHub

Tags: netlogo

[This really helpful question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817135/how-to-share-a-netlogo-model-online/37873761#comment67148764_37873761) works great for sharing a NetLogo model through a public folder in Dropbox.

However, my understanding is that [Dropbox will no longer (though for the moment still does) support sharing HTML](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16) (and so NetLogo files) this way.

The question and answer above mentioned GitHub, and in particular the URL to the "raw" HTML file, as a potential solution. *I tried this but had some problems.*

Here's the file hosted via Dropbox (it works) : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1190498/Virus%20on%20a%20Network%20(Hinze).html

Here's the identical, I think, (raw) file hosted via GitHub: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrosen48/netlogo-models/master/Virus%20on%20a%20Network%20(Hinze).html

Thinking that the key was rendering the HTML, I tried to prepend https://htmlpreview.github.io/? to the file hosted via GitHub, to no avail.

How to share a NetLogo model through GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of sad that the rules for this keep changing, but I guess there are two things that I could kind of recommend.  One is to use the [NetLogo Modeling Commons](http://modelingcommons.org).  NLW versions of models uploaded there [can be directly linked to](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/1390#model_tabs_browse_nlw), simply by uploading the `.nlogo` file—that is, you never even need to do "Export: HTML".

The other option—the option that I think I might recommend more strongly is to use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), which is essentially a free, basic web host.  You can see [here](https://littlenetlogoboy.github.io/Fireworks.html) an example of a model that I uploaded to GitHub pages.  [The setup of the repository](https://github.com/LittleNetLogoBoy/littlenetlogoboy.github.io) is quite trivial; I just made a repo named "[username].github.io", uploaded the exported HTML file, and then it was accessible from a predictable URL.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think the only trick will be having folks setup GitHub Pages, but it's certainly easy enough.